# How can I place points in the left margin while using qformat of exam class?

Tags: formatting, margins, exam

I'd like to change the formatting of questions with the points in the left margin. Using `\qformat` I seem to lose the functionality of `\pointsinmargin`. Ideas? An example:

```
\documentclass{exam} 
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion}\quad (\thepoints)\hfill}
\pointsinmargin

\begin{document}
\begin{questions} 

\question[10] How do I put the points in the right margin given I have specified them in qformat?

\noqformat
\question[10] points correctly placed but now the formatting is lost...

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer should make the desired rendering.\qformat if I have correctly understand, create a format for the label question but the question is in the other lign. So for modify the label and the question is in the same line, the answer I have found is to modify directly the \questionlabel in the right form (l3 in the code)

```
\documentclass{exam} 
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion}\quad (\thepoints)\hfill}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\hspace*{-2cm}\textbf{Question \thequestion}\quad }

\begin{document}
\begin{questions} 

\question[10] How do I put the points in the right margin given I have specified them in qformat?

\noqformat
\question[10] points correctly placed but now the formatting is lost...

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, \qformat if I have correctly understand, create a format for the label question but the question is in the other lign. So for modify the label and the question is in the same line, the answer I have found is to modify directly the \questionlabel in the right form