# Exam.cls - Formatting points in the margin

Tags: formatting, exam

Today, I'm writing my question with the `exam.cls`. I would like to format the questions like that :

[image: What expected]

But, unfortunately, it is not possible to keep points in the left margin with the `\qformat` command. So, I proceed with `\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\textbf{Question \thequestion}}` to keep `\pointsinmargin` usable as pointed in this topic : [Formatting - How can I place points in the left margin while using qformat of exam class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398858/how-can-i-place-points-in-the-left-margin-while-using-qformat-of-exam-class) .

But this leads to overlap the `\thepoints` and the label of question as you can say on this picture (zoom of the previous one btw). Also the points don't appear for question.
[image: Zoom to see the overlap]

What I expect :

- Points in the left margin with the format : `/\thepoints`
- Label of the question : `Question \thequestion` with arabic number.
- Label of the partno : `\thepartno)` with letter.
- If it is possible, points for a part has to be indented with respect to the questions points.

Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 12pt, a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[top=1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}

%% Structure Exam.cls
\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\thepartno)}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\textbf{Question \thequestion}}

\pointname{}
\pointformat{/\thepoints}
\bonuspointformat{/+\thepoints}

\pointsinmargin

\begin{document}


        \begin{questions}
        \question Définissez ce qu'est la force de pesanteur :
        \begin{parts}
            \part[2] Première question
            \part[2] Première question
        \end{parts}\vspace{2cm}

        \question[1] Définissez ce qu'est la force de pesanteur :\vspace{2.5cm}
    \end{questions}


\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

Since the `questions` environment is just a list, we can play around with the list parameters `\leftmargin` and `\labelwidth`. We change them for the questions and parts using hooks provides by the `exam` class:

```
\newlength{\mywidth}
\settowidth{\mywidth}{Question 10}
\newlength{\mywidthii}
\settowidth{\mywidthii}{Question 1000}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
\addtolength{\leftmargin}{\mywidth}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{\mywidthii}%
}

\renewcommand{\partshook}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{-0.5\mywidth}%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 12pt, a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[top=1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}

%% Structure Exam.cls
\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\thepartno)}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\textbf{Question \thequestion}}
%\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\thequestion...}

\pointname{}
\pointformat{/\thepoints}
\bonuspointformat{/+\thepoints}

\newlength{\mywidth}
\settowidth{\mywidth}{Question 10}
\newlength{\mywidthii}
\settowidth{\mywidthii}{Question 1000}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
\addtolength{\leftmargin}{\mywidth}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{\mywidthii}%
}

\renewcommand{\partshook}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{-0.5\mywidth}%
}

\pointsinleftmargin

\begin{document}

        \begin{questions}

        \question Définissez ce qu'est la force de pesanteur:
        \begin{parts}
            \part[2] Première question Première question Première question Première question Première question Première question Première question 
            \part[2] Première question
        \end{parts}\vspace{2cm}

        \question[1] Définissez ce qu'est la force de pesanteur :

        \question[1]
        \question[1]
        \question[1]
        \question[1]
        \question[1]
        \question[1]
        \question[1]
        \question[1]
        \question[1]
    \end{questions}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ow, very nice ! When i tried to change commands, the `/` for the points was always present although no points were assigned to the questions.
I guess there is still many things i do not understand about this class. Thanks to highlight that the `questions` environment is a list. I did not catch it.
Thanks for your help, it's what i wanted to do !

There is still one question about `exam` i'll write on another topic. This one is solved :) !

Comment: After use, it seems like the text do not wrap around the label. Some questions look like a block. Do you think it is possible to set the options `wide` of the `enumitem` package to those list ? I tried but i was unable to solve this problem. Maybe it is not possible to keep question and text on the same line and to wrap the text around the label.